# I want to extract the "Date" column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple code for getting a stock price data that looks like this.

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import pandas as pd

#To get BNI price data
getBNI = yf.Ticker("BBNI.JK")
priceBNI = getBNI.history(period="1mo")
```

I would like to extract the dates within the 'priceBNI' variable but I am unable to. Any idea how to extract the dates? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Use `priceBNI.Date`.

Comment: It's not a 'variable' its the index - `priceBNI.index.tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`priceBNI` is a `pd.Dataframe`, but I'm not sure if "Date" is a column or the index, so I'll cover both cases.

If "Date" is a column, just access using its name:

```
priceBNI["Date"]
```

If "Date" is the dataframe index, access the index attribute:

```
priceBNI.index
```

Both values will return a "Series-like" value. If you want to use the index like a series, use `priceBNI.index.to_series()`. If you want any of those as a list, add `.tolist()` at the end, to transform the values in the Series into a Python list.

So, assuming that the Date is the index, you could get a list of its values using this:

```
priceBNI.index.tolist()
```